# Blank Page inAppBrowser Cordova ios

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

i am using this code to launch a url via the inAppBrowser, in Android it works perfectly fine, but on IOS  it just opens the window and stays blank white without loading the url.

Please help

```
 var _ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(_url, '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no,hardwareback=no,clearsessioncache=no,clearcache=yes');
        _ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {

        });
```

Comment: Use location=yes to check the url is loading or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be one or two of the following:

1. A Content Security Policy issue. Since iOS 10.2, a CSP must be defined in your index.html file.  Without one, the URL you are attempting to reach will be blocked. A sensible one looks like:

   < meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self’; connect-src https://www.google.com; script-src 'self’; media-src *">

where you follow connect-src with the URL  ([see here for more details](https://www.netkow.com/revenge-of-the-csp-ios-10-2-and-uiwebview-issue-resolved/))

2. Add access element(s) to your config.xml file following this pattern: [(More info)](https://www.netkow.com/android-404-not-found-from-cache/)

   < access origin="*://*.google.com/*" />

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the following Content-Security-Policy:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * 'self' gap: wss: ws: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">`

Comment: Please finish the example